# Gdx.files.internal("maps/").list(); list "map" 's content, desktop

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to list in my game the content of a "map" folder which is itself in the assets folder, with `Gdx.files.internal("maps/").list();`

When compiling and launching through Eclipse, it works without any problem, I end up with the list of what "map" is containing as I want (it finds map_test.tmx and map_test2.tmx)

But when I export my jar, it doesn't work anymore.
I can still directly load my map by doing `Gdx.files.internal("maps/map_test.tmx")`, but doing `Gdx.files.internal("maps/").list();` returns nothing as if the folder never existed, while it's actually there and other assets load properly...

This is how I fetch all my maps in the maps folder :

```
private String[] getMaps() {
    FileHandle[] files = Gdx.files.internal("maps/").list();
    Array<String> maps = new Array<String>();

    for(FileHandle f : files)
        if(f.extension().equals("tmx"))
            maps.add(f.name());

    String[] result = new String[maps.size];
    for(int i = 0; i < maps.size; i++)
        result[i] = maps.get(i);

    return result;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: How did you export your jar file? Is there another `Gdx.files.internal("maps/")` that takes a `Url` parameter instead? Then you could resolve the maps folder using `this.getClass().getResource(String)` and pass the URL parameter to the method maybe?

Comment: Well, I just did "File, Export, Runnable Jar File" ... Also I don't see any other method taht could take an Url. There's only one with a String as arg

Comment: And the maps/ directory is marked as a resources directory in Eclipse? Will have a special icon in the editor.

Comment: How can I check that ? I'm not very used to tinker eclipse settings :> . I've also noticed that if I put the maps folder in the same folder the jar is in it works. All my assets are inside the jar and work, but the maps don't ...

Comment: Listing files bundled into the jar is not supported.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I have to put the map folder outside the jar then ! Thanks for the answers ! :)